# Encoding issue when reading csv - lines end with \n\x00

Tags: python, pandas, csv, encoding, ascii

I have some issues when trying to read a csv file with pandas since only the first line parses the date correctly (the next rows came in either `NaN` or `NaT`. I have tried to open the file directly to see how it looks like:

```
f = open('20191122.csv', "r", encoding='ascii')
f.read(300)
```

The first 300 characters reveal that the lines end with `\n\x00`:

```
'20191122 21:29,1,59,-999,42,-999.9,-999.9,37,34,1,0.0,0.4,0.4,0.4,0,0,0,0,0,10.1,9.6,0.0,0,33.7,36.0,75.4,29.6,14.0,59.5,32.7,6.7,6.8,0.2,-\n\x0020191122 21:30,1,59,-999,42,-999.9,-999.9,37,34,1,0.0,0.4,0.4,0.4,0,0,0,0,0,10.0,9.8,0.0,0,33.4,35.9,74.9,29.0,13.9,59.6,32.7,6.6,6.6,0.2,-\n\x0020191122 21:30,1,5'
```

When pulling row by row, the first row is OK:

```
data = f.readlines()
data[0]
'20191122 21:29,1,59,-999,42,-999.9,-999.9,37,34,1,0.0,0.4,0.4,0.4,0,0,0,0,0,10.1,9.6,0.0,0,33.7,36.0,75.4,29.6,14.0,59.5,32.7,6.7,6.8,0.2,-\n'
```

But the rest of the rows start with `\x00` thus failing to parse the dates:

```
data[1]
'\x0020191122 21:30,1,59,-999,42,-999.9,-999.9,37,34,1,0.0,0.4,0.4,0.4,0,0,0,0,0,10.0,9.8,0.0,0,33.4,35.9,74.9,29.0,13.9,59.6,32.7,6.6,6.6,0.2,-\n'
```

So the problem seems to be related to encoding? I have tried the [chardet package](https://pypi.org/project/chardet/) on the csv file which gave the same result: `ascii with confidence 1.0` but I cannot seem to find an answer to what to do with the `\x00`...

Answer (score 0):

The line ending in UTF-16 is "\n\x00".
f.readlines() puts \n as a line ending.

So try:

```
data = open(...).read()
data.encode().decode("utf-16")
```

Comment: Did not work, got following error measure:
´AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'´

Comment: Sorry, that didn't work either.. Just renders a lot of rubbish: 
'〲㤱ㄱ㈲㈠㨱㤲ㄬ㔬ⰹ㤭㤹㐬ⰲ㤭㤹㤮\u2d2c㤹⸹ⰹ㜳㌬ⰴⰱ⸰ⰰ⸰ⰴ⸰ⰴ⸰ⰴⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰ〱ㄮ㤬㘮〮〬〬㌬⸳ⰷ㘳〮㜬⸵ⰴ㤲㘮ㄬ⸴ⰰ㤵㔮㌬⸲ⰷ⸶ⰷ⸶ⰸ⸰ⰲਭ㈀\u3130ㄹ㈱′ㄲ㌺ⰰⰱ㤵\u2d2c㤹ⰹ㈴\u2d2c㤹⸹ⰹ㤭㤹㤮㌬ⰷ㐳ㄬ〮〬〬㐮〬㐮〬㐮〬〬〬〬〬ㄬ⸰ⰰ⸹ⰸ⸰ⰰⰰ㌳㐮㌬⸵ⰹ㐷㤮㈬⸹ⰰ㌱㤮㔬⸹ⰶ㈳㜮㘬㘮㘬㘮〬㈮\u2d2c\n〲㤱ㄱ㈲㈠㨱〳ㄬ㔬ⰹ㤭㤹㐬ⰲ㤭㤹㤮\u2d2c㤹⸹ⰹ㜳㌬ⰴⰱ⸰ⰰ⸰ⰴ⸰ⰴ⸰ⰴⰰⰰⰰⰰⰰ⸹ⰸ〱〮〮〬〬㌬⸳ⰰ㔳㤮㜬⸴ⰴ㠲㐮ㄬ⸳ⰵ㤵㐮㌬⸲ⰷ⸶ⰵ⸶ⰶ⸰ⰲਭ㈀\u3130ㄹ㈱′ㄲ㌺ⰱⰱ㤵\u2d2c㤹ⰹ㈴\u2d2c㤹⸹ⰹ㤭㤹㤮㌬ⰷ㐳ㄬ〮〬〬㐮〬㐮〬㐮〬〬〬〬〬㤬㜮ㄬ⸰ⰱ⸰ⰰⰰ㈳㜮㌬⸵ⰸ㐷〮㈬⸷ⰸ

Answer (score 0):

You can try to replace it!

```
if '\x00' in open(tmp_file_name).read():
    print("you have null bytes in your input file")
    fi = open(tmp_file_name, 'r')
    tmp_file_csv_data = fi.read()
    fi.close()
    fo = open(tmp_file_name, 'w')
    fo.write(tmp_file_csv_data.replace('\x00',''))
    enter code herefo.close()
```